# How to monitor a process? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows

How to monitor a process, and I don't mean "How to see how much ram and cpu a process is using,"
I mean "How to find out the information the process is using."  I want to know what data the process is processing.

Comment: generally this requires the use of a debugger, allowing you to dump process memory, or to stop execution and inspect the contents of the processes memory at particular points in execution. this is easy enough with code you compiled, using tools like IDEs but can be seriously non-trivial when working with another program that wasn't distributed with debug information.

Comment: **Thank You**..

Answer (score 1):

With PRocess Monitor:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Download: https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip